# UITableView Blank Cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

My Storyboard looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, I have a TableView below the MapView and then another TableView will appear when I click on the search bar.

My Code:

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface STLMMeetupLocation  : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDataSource, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
@end
```

.m

```
#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (tableView == self.tableView)
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"firstTableViewCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"This is a First Table View cell";
    return cell;
}

else {
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"searchBarCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
cell.textLabel.text = @"This is a Search Bar cell";
    return cell;
}

}
```

My Simulator First Screen:

[image]

My Simulator Second Screen:

[image]

Why is my simulators First screen's tableView's cell.textLabel.text Blank?  Shouldn't it have @"This is the First Table View cell"; I know I'm doing something stupid!

Comment: Your issue is for the first time right ? - When above screen appears it comes up with blank table view and after tapping on search bar cells are visible.

Comment: What do you mean first time?

Comment: Nope.  I can go back and forth between the the first screen and the second screen by hitting the Cancel button and the TableView on the first screen remains blank.

Comment: Did you connect both tableview with IBOutlet as well as delegate ??

Comment: May be issue can be in this line "if (tableView == self.tableView)" so  just try to put [self.tableView reloadData] on viewWillAppear and check

Comment: acces TableView By using tag of tableView

Comment: @Bhargavi that did not work

Comment: @sugan.s only one tableView is connected via IBOutlet and that's the first one.  The second one comes by default as part of the SearchDisplayController so I don't think I can set that one up as IBOutlet.

Comment: @iPatel I'm not sure how to set tags to searchDisplayController's tableView?

Comment: @user1107173 try to set tag for self.tableView rather and instead tableView == self.tableView match tag like tableView.tag == <Your tag>

Comment: @Bhargavi tag is not working.

Comment: as iPatel set in IBOutlet set tag for tableview from File inspector and check in cellforrow if(tablview.tag == 100){ } @user1107173

Comment: great idea about the tags guys, however, that is not working :(

Comment: @user1107173 Have you connected tableview's data source and delegate in your .storyboard? OR else you need to write in your viewDidLoad like [self.tableView setDataSource:self]; [self.tableView setDelegate:self];

Comment: @user1107173- as bhargavi sugg. first check your tableview? it has properly connected to file's Owner or not ?? check delegate and datasource and '@property' & '@synthesize' ?? my be problem is there.

Comment: @user1107173-<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> add in .h file ??

Comment: Have you try to debug your code? check first table datasource methods are called? I made sample using you code and its showing me that things which are not for you. Confirm that delegate and datasource are  connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only possible reason in your case is that you had not connected your datasource and delegate properly. If you've connected already, but still getting problems, then just disconnect all the connections and connect them again. Here's a sample image....

https://www.dropbox.com/s/y51astwgjveeixm/Screen%20Shot%202013-04-11%20at%2010.41.02%20AM.png

And also, you had used UITableViewDataSource twice.... :(

Answer (score 2):

I took your code and tried it. Works perfectly for me. I think you have written and connected perfectly for `UISearchBar` and `searchDisplayController`. But, You are missing something with the actual `tableView`.

I suggest you to just have a quick look at [THIS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view) tutorial. I am sure you will get the missing point quickly.

All the best.

Comment: Thank you for trying the code!  You are right.  Since AKB8085 answered it first, so I have to give him the credit.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```